# Scanner de código de barras para browser

Tags: javascript, ionic, plugin, typescript, scanner

O cenário é o seguinte:

- Estou criando um aplicativo em Ionic 2, porém eu preciso que ele também seja acessado através de uma URL em um browser, como o Chrome.
- Um dos requisitos desse aplicativo é que ele faça leitura de código de barras.
- Tentei usar o [plugin oficial do próprio Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/), que inclusive diz que tem suporte para browser, porém pra mim não rolou. Meu código está igualzinho ao do tutorial.
- No navegador, ao tentar acessar a função de scanner (tanto via desktop quanto mobile) ele retorna a mensagem de erro "Cordova_not_defined".
- Somente gerando o .apk e rodando no meu celular eu consegui executar a função do barcode scanner.

O que eu preciso é algo mais ou menos assim: https://github.com/code-kotis/barcode-scanner

Porém o problema deste é que, apesar do nome, ele só lê QR code, código de barras não... E sim, eu testei.

Me ajudaria bastante se alguém pudesse:

- Me informar algum plugin scanner que pode ser usado no meu aplicativo e acessado por um **browser**;
- Ou me informa uma solução para este plugin oficial do Ionic rodar no browser sem essa mensagem de erro do cordova.

Comment: Ola, ja tentou usar o [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)?